# Flutter: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: flutter

When I create a new Flutter project and try to build it to an Android device, I get the following error.

```
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] annotation-1.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] core-1.6.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] fragment-1.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] lifecycle-common-2.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] lifecycle-common-java8-2.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] tracing-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] window-java-1.0.0-beta04.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.2.0/lifecycle-common-2.2.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common-java8/2.2.0/lifecycle-common-java8-2.2.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime/2.2.0/lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/fragment/fragment/1.1.0/fragment-1.1.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.1.0/annotation-1.1.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/tracing/tracing/1.0.0/tracing-1.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.6.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.6.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.6.0/core-1.6.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
     Required by:
         project :app > io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
      > Could not resolve androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/window/window-java/1.0.0-beta04/window-java-1.0.0-beta04.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The project works quite well for the web but I get the following error when trying with an android device.

another project that I have been working on another linux device, when I try building the project on this windows machine I get the following error(the project works fine on the linux machine).

```
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-settings-api:7.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.4.2 > com.android.tools:common:30.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.4.2
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.4.2
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta10
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta10
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :sqflite > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.4.2 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.10
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 21s
```

This project that I was working on the linux machine doesn't even build for the web on the windows machine.

I know and I understand this might not be enough data to fix the issue, but please let me know what more info you need and I'll update the question accordingly. Please do not close the question with the reason `Needs debugging details`. this is project that has just been created and I have no clue what more info to give.